# How can show only the characters after dash ( - )?

Tags: foreach, character, smarty

I have the title ( Architectural_Garden_Hardware-Switch Plates & Outlet Covers )

But i whant show only the characters after dash ( - ) like ( Switch Plates & Outlet Covers )\

How can do that?

```
{foreach from=elements item=birds}
   <option value="{$birds}">{$birds}</option>
/foreach}
```

Comment: What programming language are you talking about? Please specify this by adding a tag,

Comment: I working with PHP language, and smarty engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use strpos and substr as in the following example:

```
{assign var="var" value=" ( Architectural_Garden_Hardware-Switch Plates & Outlet Covers )"}
{assign var="pos" value=$var|strpos:"-"}
{$var|substr:($pos+1)}
```

You could also use shorter syntax:

```
{assign var="var" value=" ( Architectural_Garden_Hardware-Switch Plates & Outlet Covers )"}
{$var|substr:($var|strpos:"-"+1)}
```

so in your case you could probably use:

```
{foreach from=elements item=birds}
   <option value="{$birds|substr:($birds|strpos:"-"+1)}">{$birds|substr:($birds|strpos:"-"+1)}</option>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: This need put it in foreach or out? Because i try it and is not working

Comment: @user3673602 I've added more code to my answer and also shorter expression without extra variable

Comment: @user3673602 Maybe not, but you haven't mentioned about Smarty 2 in your question and haven't added Smarty 3 tag